# No llega el archivo de desde Ionic/Angular a Backend en NodeJs

Tags: nodejs, angular, ionic, fileupload

Tengo un servicio en angular para subir las imagenes a un servidor en Node con Express.fileUpload, lo curioso es que desde Postman funciona perfecto y desde Angular tambien funcionaba, pero no recuerdo si he tocado algo que no logro encontrar o ha sido a causa de implementar un HTTPinterceptor, pero el servidor responde con un resquest.files? nulo ( no llega ningun archivo )...

El servicio es el siguiente:

```
SubirImagen(foto: string) {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    token: this.userService.usuario.token,
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
  });

  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('archivo', this.dataURItoBlob(foto), 'Imagen.jpg');

  return this.httpClient.post(
    `${this.config.configUrl}/upload/fotosAvisos`,
    formData,
    { headers }
  );
}
```

La función para la conversión del dataUri a Blob es esta (La imagen es capturada con el plugin nativo de Capacitor)

```
dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
// 'dataURI:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4UbyRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAg...'
  try {
    let byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) {
      byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    } else {
      byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    }

    const mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    console.log(mimeString); // 'image/jpeg'
    console.log(byteString); // 'ÿØÿáFòExif...'

    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    const int8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      int8Array[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([int8Array], { type: mimeString });
    console.log('blob ', blob);
      // Blob {size: 2120696, type: "image/jpeg"}
      // size: 2120696
      // type: "image/jpeg"
    return blob;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('catch ', error);
  }
}
```

En el interceptor solo tiene la función de hacer el refresco del token, de añadirlo o incorporar las cabeceras necesarias si no las tuviera, pero no controlo las peticiones que contengan 'formData' y esta como lleva las cabeceras desde el servicio, pues no se clona la petición, por lo que no le veo el problema...

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el problema, todo venía del httpinterceptor, por forzar un

```
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

... Sin ello, funciona perfectamente...